# c/gtk convert structure to the type of GtkWindow

Tags: c, gtk

I have the following structure,

```
    typedef struct _MainWin
    {
        GtkWindow parent;
        GtkWidget* scroll;
        GtkWidget* box;
    }MainWin;
```

I have created the application main window from this structure. Now I need the main window in full screen. When I tried to call,

```
gtk_window_fullscree(GTK_WINDOW(mw);
```

Where `mw` is object of `MainWin`. I got the following error message `gtk_window_fullscreen: assertion`GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed`

How can I lead `mw` to `GtkWindow`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems wrong. Your GtkWindow should be a pointer too, and created using `gtk_window_new()` like any other GTK+ widget. This looks like you're trying to "subclass" the GtkWindow struct, which I don't think you can do like this.

Comment: I created window with gtk_window_new() after calling gtk_window_fulscreen(...).

Comment: I try to make like here: http://github.com/xsisqox/Viewnior/blob/master/src/vnr-window.h

Comment: Do you have all the other stuff that goes along with subclassing a GtkWindow?

Perhaps it would be a good idea to post a bit more code so we can see if you did it correctly, but if you called `gtk_window_new()` and your MainWin is declared as above then you are in fact doing several things wrong.

Also there's no real reason to subclass a GtkWindow most of the time, so you may want to just not bother with that part

Comment: Actually, for large multi-document applications, subclassing GtkWindow is quite common.

Comment: @ptomato: Sure, which is what "like this" is referring to.

Comment: @unwind, Sorry, I meant that in response to spudd86's comment that there's no real reason to subclass.

Comment: @ptomato yea, but it doesn't look like this is all that complex and subclassing is probably not needed, or even really desirable here

Answer (score 1):

What they did in the Viewnior code that you posted is to make a subclass of `GtkWindow`. You have copied part of the code to do that properly, but not all of it. You should read the tutorial part of the GObject documentation on how to define new classes. You can find it online [here](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/stable/pt02.html).